# Can I retain the state of Fragments in ViewPager but not actually instantiate it?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I know there's `setUserVisibleHint` I can utilize but this isn't what I'm looking for.

For example, I have 9 pages in `ViewPager`. I want to keep the state of those pages, so I call `setOffscreenPageLimit(8)` which does the job, but I only want the current and the next `Fragment` gets instantiated which means only max 2 `onActivityCreated()` would be called at a time. Is it possible?

Comment: "I want to keep the state of those pages, so I call setOffscreenPageLimit(8) which does the job" -- not exactly. It keeps the *pages*, not their state. If you only want to keep the state for excess pages, use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` rather than `FragmentPagerAdapter`, and do not call `setOffscreenPageLimit()`.

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be to implement your own state management and get rid of `setOffScreenPageLimit()`

Comment: Each `Fragment` has a `RecyclerView` that user might scroll. I want to retain the state (position in the list, text, image, etc) of all the pages, but I don't want all `onActivityCreated()` are called at once.

Comment: Try override **destroyItem** of your FragmentPagerrAdapter to do nothing [default is, `container.removeView((View)object);`, which removed the just viewed fragment], so viewed fragments will not be destoryed. Hope that helps!